# How to make background in full screen?

Tags: android

I wrote code with guide to move my background in game and it's working, but the  size of my background is original and I want to make the size of my moving background in full screen, please, help me))

Code:

```
public class Background extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Bitmap backGround;

public Background(Context context) {
    super(context);
    backGround = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.cold_planet);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    doDrawRunning(canvas);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}

/**
 * Draws current state of the game Canvas.
 */

private int mBGFarMoveX = 0;
private int mBGNearMoveX = 0;

private void doDrawRunning(Canvas canvas) {

    // decrement the far background
    mBGFarMoveX = mBGFarMoveX - 1;

    // decrement the near background
    mBGNearMoveX = mBGNearMoveX - 4;

    // calculate the wrap factor for matching image draw
    int newFarX = backGround.getWidth() - (-mBGFarMoveX);

    // if we have scrolled all the way, reset to start
    if (newFarX <= 0) {
        mBGFarMoveX = 0;
        // only need one draw
        canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 5000, null);

    } else {
        // need to draw original and wrap
        canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, mBGFarMoveX, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(backGround, newFarX, 0, null);
    }

}
```

}

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a transformation matrix built for ScaleToFit.CENTER. For example:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setRectToRect(new RectF(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight()), new RectF(0, 0,  reqWidth, reqHeight), Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
return Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), m, true);
```

Comment: thank you, but where i should add this part of code?